# Cleveref range format for gb4e “(1a-c)"

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, linguistics, gb4e

I managed to get cross-referencing with cleveref to examples in the format "examples (1a-1c)" using

```
\crefrangeformat{xnumi}{examples~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
```

but how can I get "examples (1a-c)"?

I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135151/38205), but I'm afraid the solution is dependent to the package in use, in this case `gb4e`, so I decided to post my answer anyway.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\crefname{xnumi}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumi}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumii}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumii}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumiii}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumiii}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumiv}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumiv}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{xnumi}{examples~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{xnumii}{examples~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangemultiformat{xnumii}{examples~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}{ and~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}{, (#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}{ and~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}

\section{Prova}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{e:pro} uno due tre
\begin{xlist}
\ex\label{e:1} uno
\ex\label{e:2} due
\ex\label{e:3} tre
\ex\label{e:4} quattro
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

In \cref{e:pro}, in \crefrange{e:1}{e:3}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, and doesn't quite work at the moment, since it only works in the case that there are no other examples between the referenced examples in the text. This is obviously unacceptable as a general solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@xnumii{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[sort&compress]{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\crefname{xnumi}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumi}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumii}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumii}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumiii}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumiii}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefname{xnumiv}{example}{examples}
\creflabelformat{xnumiv}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{xnumi}{examples~(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangeformat{xnumii}{examples~(#3\arabic{xnumi}#1#4--#5#2#6)}
\crefrangemultiformat{xnumii}{examples~(#3\arabic{xnumi}#1#4--#5#2#6)}
{ and~(#3\arabic{xnumi}#1#4--#5#2#6)}{, (#3\arabic{xnumi}#1#4--#5#2#6)}
{ and~(#3\arabic{xnumi}#1#4--#5#2#6)}


\begin{document}

\section{Prova}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{e:pro} uno due tre
\begin{xlist}
\ex\label{e:1} uno
\ex\label{e:2} due
\ex\label{e:3} tre
\ex\label{e:4} quattro 
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

In \cref{e:pro}, in \crefrange{e:1}{e:3}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @Mico The wonders of cut and paste. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn No, it doesn't work. Try setting another `exe` environment between the original one and the references. Your `\crefrangeformat` command always uses the current value of `xnumi`.

Comment: @egreg: It worked for me. But when you use \cref with subexamples you get only the letter now. \cref{e:1} = example (a).

Comment: EDIT: Stupid of me. I've changed xnumii format to `\creflabelformat{xnumii}{(#2\arabic{xnumi}#1#3)}` and now it works correctly.

Comment: @Stefano egreg is right.  It doesn't work.  Can you unaccept the answer?  I'd like to delete it if I can't fix it.