# How to cross-reference a list of sub figures at once?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref, cite-package

How can I define a command similar to `\ref` for referencing a list of subfigures at once?
Just like what `cite` package does for citations.

A command like `\myref{a,c,d}` which can be tuned to generate the following outputs for the below MWE:
`1a,c,d`, `1(a,c,d)`.

It would be great if it can group the labels together for example `\myref{a,b,c,d}` will generate `1a--d`.

Is there any package which implements this kind of cross-referencing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[][]{Plot 1 \label{a}} 
\subfloat[][]{Plot 2 \label{b}}  \\
\subfloat[][]{Plot 3 \label{c}} 
\subfloat[][]{Plot 4 \label{d}} 
\end{figure}

\noindent Note: \\
Fig.~\ref{a} \\ 
Fig.~\ref{a},b \\
How to generate the following cross-references? \\    
Fig.~1a,b \\ 
Fig.~1a,b \\
Fig.~1a,c,d \\
Fig.~1a--d \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) for referencing and the code provided here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135151/crossreference-in-ref-range-1a-1e-to-1a-e to to adjust the output.

Answer (score 4):

Your example combined with the code provided by Toby Cubitt (the author of `cleveref`) in [Crossreference in Ref Range [(1a-1e) to (1a-e)]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135151/crossreference-in-ref-range-1a-1e-to-1a-e)  could be a starter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\crefstripprefix[2]{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\@toksa{#1}%
    \edef\@toksb{#2}%
    \def\@accum{}%
    \@crefstripprefix%
    \@result%
  \endgroup}

\def\@crefstripprefix{%
  \let\@iterate\relax%
  \def\accum@flag{0}%
  \let\@tempc\@tempb%
  \cref@poptok{\@toksa}{\@tempa}%
  \cref@poptok{\@toksb}{\@tempb}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\relax%
    \def\@iterate{\@crefstripprefix}%
    \ifx\@accum\@empty\relax%
      \let\@accum\@tempb%
    \else%
      \ifcat\@tempb\@tempc\relax%
        \ifcat\@tempb a\relax%
          \def\accum@flag{1}%
        \else%
          \expandafter\chardef\expandafter\@tempa%
            \expandafter=\expandafter`\@tempb\relax%
          \ifnum\@tempa>`/\relax%
            \expandafter\ifnum\@tempb<`:\relax%
              \def\accum@flag{1}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
        \fi%
      \fi%
      \def\@tempa{1}%
      \ifx\accum@flag\@tempa%
        \edef\@accum{\@accum\@tempb}%
      \else%
        \let\@accum\@empty%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \ifcat\@tempb\@tempc\relax\else%
      \let\@accum\@empty%
    \fi%
    \edef\@result{\@accum\@tempb\@toksb}%
  \fi%
  \@iterate}

\def\cref@poptok#1#2{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@cref@firsttok#1\@nil}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@cref@poptok#1\@nil}}
\def\@cref@firsttok#1#2\@nil{#1}
\def\@cref@poptok#1#2\@nil{#2}
\makeatother

\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[][]{Plot 1 \label{a}} 
\subfloat[][]{Plot 2 \label{b}}  \\
\subfloat[][]{Plot 3 \label{c}} 
\subfloat[][]{Plot 4 \label{d}} 
\end{figure}

\noindent Note: \\
\Cref{a} \\ 
\Cref{a,b} \\
\Cref{a,c,d} \\
\Crefrange{a}{d} \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

It should be possible to customize the output further according to your needs from here on.