# customizing cleveref for pair of subfigure references: [1a and b] instead of [1a and 1b]

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

I am using the `cleveref` package and I am very happy with it. However, I encountered one problem I wasn't able to solve. I am probably
just not combining the syntax correctly. This is highly connected
to the question already asked, here: [Crossreference in Ref Range [(1a-1e) to (1a-e)]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135151/crossreference-in-ref-range-1a-1e-to-1a-e) I am sorry if this is already answered.

The above thread explains how to reference ranges of subequations (or floats)
like 1a to e, rather than the default 1a to 1e. I would like to have the same feature for a pair of references combined by an "and", namely: 1a and b rather than the default 1a and 1b.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{figs.~#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1a}}
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1b}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1c}}
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1d}}\\
  \caption{\label{fig:1}my figures}
\end{figure}

Referencing a range works as wanted and gives figs. 1a-b: \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b,subfig:1c,subfig:1d}.\\
But, referencing a pair gives \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b}, rather than the desired figs. 1a and b.\\ 

\end{document}
```

I think combining `\crefstripprefix` together with `\crefmultiformat{figure}` (which I use in the MWE to remove the "()") could give me the desired result. But I am not able to get the correct syntax to make this work, since I am pretty unfamiliar with the deep-down latex syntax.

Answer (score 4):

In your definition of `\crefmultiformat` you want to use `\crefrefstripprefix` in the second argument using a value from the first argument.  This can be achieved as follows:

```
\crefmultiformat{figure}{figs.~#2#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#3}%
 { and~#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}
```

Also you need to define `\crefrangelabelformat` in a similar way (update following comments).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subfig}

\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#4--%
#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{figs.~#2#1\xdef\mycreffirstarg{#1}#3}%
{ and~#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}%
{, #2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}%
{ and~#2{\crefstripprefix{\mycreffirstarg}{#1}}#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{figure}{figs.~#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}%
{ and~#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}%
{, #3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}%
{ and~#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1a}}
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1b}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1c}}
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1d}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1e}}
  \caption{\label{fig:1}my figures}
\end{figure}

\tracingmacros=1
Referencing a range works as wanted and gives figs.~1a--d:
\cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b,subfig:1c,subfig:1d}.

Gives figs.~1a--c and e: \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b,subfig:1c,subfig:1e}.

Gives figs.~1a, b, d and e: \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b,subfig:1d,subfig:1e}.

Also referencing a pair gives \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b}, which is
then the desired figs.~1a and~b.    

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me this fails if there is a range: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672267/cleveref-with-subcaption-using-crefmultiformat-and-crefstripprefix

Comment: @Chachni I you code in that question you use `\edef` instead of `\xdef`.  The latter is needed to make a global assignment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see the code in my question works with \xdef instead of \edef. But I then don't understand why your code fails when I add another subfloat     \subfloat[][]{\rule{2.cm}{2.cm}\label{subfig:1e}}\\ and reference to \cref{subfig:1a,subfig:1b,subfig:1c,subfig:1e}

Comment: @Chachni Thanks for pointing out that combination.  It turns out that in the `abce` case, the first part gets past to the range constructor, so this also needs to define the `\mycreffirstarg` macro.  Code updated.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @AndrewSwann!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig` will get you most of the way. `subcaption` provides a `\subref` command, which gives you only the subfigure index without the figure number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image a}
  \label{subfig:foo}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Image b}
  \label{subfig:bar}
  \end{subfigure}\\
  \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{Image c}
  \label{subfig:baz}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Image d}
  \label{subfig:qux}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\label{fig:1}my figures}
\end{figure}
Referencing a range works as wanted and gives figs.~\ref{subfig:foo}--\subref{subfig:bar}. There is also \cref{subfig:foo,subfig:bar,subfig:baz,subfig:qux}.
A pair can be referenced like figs.~\ref{subfig:foo} to \subref{subfig:baz}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, this workaround works, but the whole point of using `cleveref` is to avoid such manual specification of the names and labels.

Comment: Surely hard-coding `1a-b` is cheating, at least! Well, the rest undermines the point of `cleveref`, but this bit undermines the point of using the `\label`-`\ref` system to boot.

Comment: @HugoRaguet Yes, but I simply used the MWE provided by the OP and changed only the commands. I've edited the answer to remove the original hard-coded part as well.

Comment: @erik: By manual specification, I was actually thinking of the "figs.", the "to" and the "\subref" parts. Otherwise, there is no use in using `cleveref`, as also mentioned by cfr.