# cleveref with subcaption, using \crefmultiformat and \crefstripprefix

Tags: subcaption, cleveref

I am trying to implement this solution:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418261/194338
or this solution:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416838/194338

but both fail in my case. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}{#3#1#4 to #5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\crefmultiformat{figure}%
  {\edef\mycrefprefixinfo{#1}figs.~#2#1#3}%
  { and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%  <- cannot access \mycrefprefixinfo when there is a range created
  {, #2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
  {, and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}

 
\begin{document}

\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:2,fig:test:3} % works: figs. 1a to c
\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:3} % works: figs. 1a and c
\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:3,fig:test:4} % works: figs. 1a, c, and d
\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:2,fig:test:3,fig:test:5} % fails, should be figs. 1a to c and e

\begin{figure}
\centering
{\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:test:1}}%
{\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:test:2}}%
{\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:test:3}}%
{\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:test:4}}%
{\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:test:5}}%
\caption{General caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Basically it seems to fail when it creates a range. From my tests, it seems that when there is a range, the parameter `\mycrefprefixinfo` is not anymore accessible in the third argument of \crefmultiformat

Comment: You need to use `\xdef` instead of `\edef` as in my original code.  `\xdef` not only expands but makes a global assignment, rather than a local one.

Comment: Thanks, it worked here

Answer (score 0):

So based on @AndrewSwann comment and @AndrewSwann's updated answer here: [customizing cleveref for pair of subfigure references: [1a and b] instead of [1a and 1b]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155292/customizing-cleveref-for-pair-of-subfigure-references-1a-and-b-instead-of-1a/416838#416838)

2 modifications are necessary: change `\edef` to `\xdef` and also add the definition of the variable `\mycrefprefixinfo` inside `\crefrangelabelformat`:

```
\crefrangelabelformat{figure}%
  {\xdef\mycrefprefixinfo{#1}#3#1#4 to #5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6}

\crefmultiformat{figure}%
  {\xdef\mycrefprefixinfo{#1}figs.~#2#1#3}%
  { and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
  {, #2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
  {, and~#2\crefstripprefix{\mycrefprefixinfo}{#1}#3}
```

Depending on usecase, one might also need to redefine `\crefrangemultiformat`

Adding the definition of the variable `\mycrefprefixinfo` inside `\crefrangelabelformat` is necessary for the code above if one only calls `\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:2,fig:test:3,fig:test:5}`, without calling `\cref{fig:test:1,fig:test:3}`, which puts the definition of `\mycrefprefixinfo` in the global space.